# Is 'auxiliary equation' or 'characteristic equation' more common?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

In my school textbook, when solving second order homogeneous differential equations it talks about using the equation's '**auxiliary equation**'.

However, I've seen in many places, such as Wikipedia, that the term '**characteristic equation**' is used instead.

Which one is more standard? Are they both alright? If I write an article is it ok to talk about either of them?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Both are acceptable, but 'characteristic equation' is more common according to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=characteristic%20equation%2Cauxiliary%20equation&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=20&case_insensitive=true):

[image: Google Ngram]

If you were writing an article about them, then it would probably be safest to write something like

> The characteristic equation (or auxiliary equation) of $y''+4y'-5=0$
> is $m^2+4m-5=0$.

when you use this terminology for the first time. It would be a little clunky to use both phrases throughout the article, and so it is better in my opinion to be choose one of them and be consistent.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe! I'll wait a bit before accepting your answer in case someone else has anything else to say.

Comment: About that Ngram.  Of course "characteristic equation" is very common in uses other than linear DE.  So unless you can somehow restrict to DE texts, it does not tell us much about this question.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: GEdgar makes a very valid point. However, I have looked at the search results for solving second order differential equations, and the majority do use the terminology 'characteristic equation'.